# Почему нет подсказки на OnClickListener, а на OnLongClickListener есть?

Tags: android-studio, java

Хочу научиться писать обработчик кнопки, как описано в стартандроиде. Я уже пытался это сделать месяц назад в **Eclipse**, но понял, что надо читать еще Java. Но по работе IDE у меня тогда вопросов не возникло - все работало четко и без косяков.

Сейчас, подучив Java, я вновь приступил к этому вопросу. На этот раз в **Android Studio**. Но возникли проблемы.

Вот в чем дело:
Я создаю пустой проект, потом добавляю кнопку и текстовое поле. Далее я начинаю создавать объект View.OnClickListener (для обработки нажатий кнопки). Для этого я набираю *OnClick*, но в выпадающем меню нет такого интерфейса, а есть DialogInterface.OnClickListener? Почему это так? В Eclipse был же.

В то же время в выпадающем меню есть View.OnLongClickListener. Почему один интерфейс из одного уровня иерархии есть, второго нету (т.е. android.view.View.OnLongClickListener в выпадающем меню есть, а android.view.View.OnClickListener нету)?

```
import android.content.DialogInterface; //
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener myckl;//ДОБАВИЛ КАК ПРЕДЛАГАЛОСЬ ИЗ DialogInterface, а не View

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: @panzermarin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[image: img] Установите пакеты в SDK Manager, включая extras.

Comment: Какие именно? У меня вроде бы все что нужно установленою
И че вопрос заминусили?

Comment: Все, вопрос решен - скачал новую, уже не бета версию Android Studio (т.е. 1.0.2). Переустановил. Все работает без замечаний.

Comment: я вам ничего не минусил